# Django slugs not unique with unique=True

Tags: django

I created two articles with the title "test" and this is what the second one generates as an error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "xxx_content_slug_xxxx_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (slug)=(test) already exists.
```

Knowing that this is my model:

```
class Content()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Content, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and knowing that I made the migration in the DB.

I don't know how to solve that.

Note: The problem is generated from the class post that inherits the content class and I don't think this information would help in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slugify` does not check for uniqueness, so if you create two articles with the same title, `slugify(self.title)` is going to generate the same slug twice, which will of course cause the database to complain about a violation of the unique constraint.

Setting `unique = True` on a field, will not automatically create unique values for every new instance, it'll only create a constraint on the database that the same value can not be saved twice.

You can use [django-autoslug](https://pypi.org/project/django-autoslug/), which is a library that does exactly what you need.

Simply install the package, and implement your fields like this:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Model
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class Content(models.Model)
    title = CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
```

`AutoSlugField` does the following:

> 1. populate itself from another field,
> 2. preserve uniqueness of the value and
> 3. use custom slugify() functions for better i18n.

(Also, I assume that `Content` is a subclass of `Model`, otherwise your code wouldn't work at all.)